# What is the difference between IIS and Websphere?

Tags: iis, websphere, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, application-server

I know IIS is a web server and Websphere is an application server, but what exactly does that mean at a more granular level?  For instance, why can't something created in Websphere exist in IIS and vice-versa?  It's especially confusing when I see servers that are running both in tandem, as they seem to have some of the same traits.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

They're designed to run different types of applications (different programming models) and provide very different services to to those applications. But you are right that conceptually they are not very different at all.

Of course IIS grew "up" into a pseudo application server, and WebSphere has the basics of a webserver in its guts.

When they're used together, IIS is generally used as a basic webserver + gateway (reverse proxy) as WAS is not really intended to run in the DMZ.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So essentially, IIS is used in conjunction with websphere (or other app servers) to spray that dynaminc content to the end users?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, Just find it.

To install the WebSphere plug-in on an IIS server

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_SETTING_UP_DOMINO_FOR_MICROSOFT_IIS_5182_STEPS.html